# MySQL Query Two Table Join

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

having a little trouble with this query.  I have two tables ...

```
Account -
ResourceID (int)
AccountID (int) (unique auto-inc)

Resource -
TextName (varchar)
ResourceID (int) (unique auto-inc)
CompanyID (int)
```

All I have is the AccountID and I Need to make 1 query that will tell me the TextName and ResourceID of all records in the Resource table who have the same CompanyID as the record in the account table that has the same ResourceID and the AccountID that I provide.

Here is what I have so far and already it has narrowed it down to only one entry ... and I have not even begun to try to incorporate the CompanyID yet.

```
SELECT r.ResId, r.FirstName, r.LastName
FROM account a, resource r
WHERE a.AccId='7' AND a.ResId = r.ResId
```

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Is there a CompanyID field in the Account table?

Comment: Unfortunately no, that would make it much easier :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an auto join to get the similar resource sharing the company !

```
SELECT rSameCompany.ResId, rSameCompany.FirstName, rSameCompany.LastName
FROM resource r
    INNER JOIN resource rSameCompany
        ON r.CompanyID = rSameCompany.CompanyID 
    INNER JOIN account a
        ON r.ResourceID = a.ResourceID 
        AND a.AccId='7'
```

Comment: I believe you are on the right track here. But this pulls up two of the same record.  I get the same result as my query, but twice ..   which is the ResID (and name) of the record that owns the AccountID in the account table.

Comment: I made a mistake, it is not easy whithout testing it :) It have to work now !

Answer (score 0):

You want to [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) on `Account.ResourceID = Resource.ResourceID`.